# Recorrer directorios y subdirectorios, para modificar archivos con pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo una carpeta llamada "XLS", la cual tiene subcarpetas, cada una con el nombre de uno de los meses del año. En cada una de dichas subcarpetas, hay archivos que se han generado de forma diaria (Ejemplo: "XLS\Enero\04012022", "XLS\Enero\05012022" y así sucesivamente), cada uno de los cuales necesito recorrer y modificar con Python.

En principio, realicé un archivo .py en cada una de las carpetas de los meses y las recorrí con `os.listdir` y el ciclo `for`. Ahora, lo que necesito, es que en vez de tener un archivo en cada subcarpeta haciendo el recorrido por separado, tenga un archivo en el directorio principal ("XLS"), con el cual pueda entrar a cada una de las carpetas y modificar cada uno de los archivos.

Intenté hacerlo de nuevo con `os.listdir` y con dos ciclos `for` pero Python me arroja el siguiente error, ya que indica que no consigue el subdirectorio:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\kccon\OneDrive\Documentos\Reporte DEM\Reportes Cristian - originales\Completa.py", line 6, in 
> subfiles = os.listdir(j)
> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada: 'Enero'

Dejo mi código:

```
import pandas as pd  
import os

files = os.listdir("XLS")  
for j in files:  
    subfiles = os.listdir(j)  
    for i in subfiles:  
        if i[13:] == "xlsx":  
            df = pd.read_excel(i)  
            if df["DOCUMENTO_CLIENTE"].dtype == "int64":  
                df["DOCUMENTO_CLIENTE"] = df["DOCUMENTO_CLIENTE"].astype(str)  
            df["RUT"] = df[["DOCUMENTO_CLIENTE", "DOCUMENTO_CLIENTE_DV"]].apply("-".join, axis=1)  
            fecha = i[4:6] + "/" + i[6:8] + "/" + i[8:12]  
            df["Fecha_archivo"] = pd.to_datetime(fecha, dayfirst=True)  
            df["FECHA_ESTADO_AGENDADO"] = pd.to_datetime(df["FECHA_ESTADO_AGENDADO"], dayfirst=True)  
            df["Antiguedad"] = df["Fecha_archivo"] - df["FECHA_ESTADO_AGENDADO"]  
            df =             df.sort_values("Antiguedad", ascending=True)  
            df = df.drop(["ID_ORDEN", "ID_DE_ACCION_DE_ORDEN", "DOCUMENTO_CLIENTE_TIPO", "ID_SALESFORCE", "CANAL", "ES_PORTABILIDAD", "TIPO_DE_PLAN", "FECHA_ALTA", "MONTH_FINALIZATION","SERIE", "TIPO_DE_RECURSO", "DESCRIPTIVO_SKU", "MSISDN", "CHR_NOMBRE_TIPO_CLTE", "CHR_SUBTIPO_CLIENTE", "NUMERO_DE_GUIA_DE_DESPACHO", "ID_ASIGNACION_OTR","DOCUMENTO_CLIENTE","DOCUMENTO_CLIENTE_DV"], axis=1)  
            df = df.drop_duplicates("ID_ORDEN_DE_DESPACHO")  
            df.to_excel(i[:12] +"_new.xlsx")  ;     df["RUT"] = df[["DOCUMENTO_CLIENTE", "DOCUMENTO_CLIENTE_DV"]].apply("-".join, axis=1)  
            fecha = i[4:6] + "/" + i[6:8] + "/" + i[8:12]  
            df["Fecha_archivo"] = pd.to_datetime(fecha, dayfirst=True)  
            df["FECHA_ESTADO_AGENDADO"] = pd.to_datetime(df["FECHA_ESTADO_AGENDADO"], dayfirst=True)  
            df["Antiguedad"] = df["Fecha_archivo"] - df["FECHA_ESTADO_AGENDADO"]  
            df =             df.sort_values("Antiguedad", ascending=True)  
            df = df.drop(["ID_ORDEN", "ID_DE_ACCION_DE_ORDEN", "DOCUMENTO_CLIENTE_TIPO", "ID_SALESFORCE", "CANAL", "ES_PORTABILIDAD", "TIPO_DE_PLAN", "FECHA_ALTA", "MONTH_FINALIZATION","SERIE", "TIPO_DE_RECURSO", "DESCRIPTIVO_SKU", "MSISDN", "CHR_NOMBRE_TIPO_CLTE", "CHR_SUBTIPO_CLIENTE", "NUMERO_DE_GUIA_DE_DESPACHO", "ID_ASIGNACION_OTR","DOCUMENTO_CLIENTE","DOCUMENTO_CLIENTE_DV"], axis=1)  
            df = df.drop_duplicates("ID_ORDEN_DE_DESPACHO")  
            df.to_excel(i[:12] +"_new.xlsx")
```

Comment: Buen día, por favor agrega a tu pregunta el error como texto, no como imagen, tal cual aparece. Puedes presionar [edit] para modificar tu pregunta.

Comment: Hola muy buen día. Muchas gracias por la sugerencia. Ya incluí el detalle del mensaje de error. Saludos y Feliz día.

Comment: Prueba con `subfiles = os.listdir("XLS\" + j)`

Comment: Hola Patricio, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Probé como me indicas y ahora no me reconoce los archivos en el subdirectorio:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kccon\OneDrive\Documentos\Reporte DEM\Reportes Cristian - originales\Completa.py", line 9, in <module>
    df = pd.read_excel(i)
  File "C:\Users\kccon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

Comment: File "C:\Users\kccon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 457, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)
  File "C:\Users\kccon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 1376, in __init__
    ext = inspect_excel_format(
  File "C:\Users\kccon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 1250, in inspect_excel_format
    with get_handle(

Comment: File "C:\Users\kccon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 795, in get_handle
    handle = open(handle, ioargs.mode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '04012022.xlsx'

Answer (score 1):

Logré resolverlo. Gracias al aporte de [Patricio Moracho](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/31764/patricio-moracho), quien me recomendó agregar a `subfiles = os.listdir`, la cadena `"XLS\" + j`, quedando como `subfiles = os.listdir("XLS\" + j)`. Al realizarlo, Python reconoció la ruta pero no lograba abrir los xslx con `pd.to_excel(i)`. Así que, siguiendo la lógica de la recomendación de Patricio, agregué `"XLS/"+j+"/"+i` a `pd.to_excel`, quedando `df=pd.to_excel("XLS/"+j+"/"+i)` y funcionó.

Comparto mi código completo, con las correcciones indicadas:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

files = os.listdir("XLS")
for j in files[1:]:
    subfiles = os.listdir("XLS/"+j)
    for i in subfiles:
        if i[13:] == "xlsx":
            df = pd.read_excel("XLS/"+j+"/"+i)
            if df["DOCUMENTO_CLIENTE"].dtype == "int64":
                df["DOCUMENTO_CLIENTE"] = df["DOCUMENTO_CLIENTE"].astype(str)
            df["RUT"] = df[["DOCUMENTO_CLIENTE", "DOCUMENTO_CLIENTE_DV"]].apply("-".join, axis=1)
            fecha = i[4:6] + "/" + i[6:8] + "/" + i[8:12]
            df["Fecha_archivo"] = pd.to_datetime(fecha, dayfirst=True)
            df["FECHA_ESTADO_AGENDADO"] = pd.to_datetime(df["FECHA_ESTADO_AGENDADO"], dayfirst=True)
            df["Antiguedad"] = df["Fecha_archivo"] - df["FECHA_ESTADO_AGENDADO"]
            df = df.sort_values("Antiguedad", ascending=True)
            df = df.drop(["ID_ORDEN", "ID_DE_ACCION_DE_ORDEN", "DOCUMENTO_CLIENTE_TIPO", "ID_SALESFORCE", "CANAL", "ES_PORTABILIDAD", "TIPO_DE_PLAN", "FECHA_ALTA", "MONTH_FINALIZATION","SERIE", "TIPO_DE_RECURSO", "DESCRIPTIVO_SKU", "MSISDN", "CHR_NOMBRE_TIPO_CLTE", "CHR_SUBTIPO_CLIENTE", "NUMERO_DE_GUIA_DE_DESPACHO", "ID_ASIGNACION_OTR","DOCUMENTO_CLIENTE","DOCUMENTO_CLIENTE_DV"], axis=1)
            df = df.drop_duplicates("ID_ORDEN_DE_DESPACHO")
            df.to_excel(i[:12] +"_new.xlsx")
```

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.